# Desktop dies after upgrade (re-write)

Tags: upgrade, 23.04

I have a HP Desktop and if you need specs I can provide them. So, after receiving a notice that a upgrade was available. At the time I was running Ubuntu 22.04 and was having some issues with various items afterward. Research showed that this upgrade may correct the problems caused by previous upgrade. With some trepidation I began the 23.04 upgrade.

It all was good until a notice to restart popped up in the middle of the process. I still don't know what that was all about.  With no data for the reboot request and how the reboot would occur left me little choice. I watched the screen for any additional notices for the next 30 min's and all appeared OK. I left the room for a few minutes and when I returned the screen was black with a blinking cursor. Not knowing if the upgrade completed or was stopped for another reason I ended up shutting the PC down and restarting.  This is when I realized the depth of my troubles.

I went to Ask Ubuntu for help and received a suggestion and started working it. When I entered sudo umount /dev/sda1 command and sudo no longer worked and I did find out later that a reboot would bring it back. Well, it took me 4+ hrs to get a failsafe screen to come up. That's where I'm at now, I need to know how to correct the upgrade.

My display, internet, and other items are not working.  I don't know if the failsafe mode is keeping me from the internet and all three of my browsers from opening. The terminal program can get to the internet and retrieve from the snap store and get updates. Multiple programs are not working or have limited abilities.

I need to get the system up without having to use tricks and gimmicks to use my desktop. I would like it the function as it did previous to the last 3 upgrades. Mainly, I would like to know what I can do to help myself here. Can someone help?
I was asked to clarify my original post and hope that I have done so here. Thanks for your time and effort reading this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Release upgrades are considered to be version upgrades in Ubuntu. Ubuntu 22.04 currently has no supported release upgrades until the next LTS version Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is released in April, 2024. Somehow or other Ubuntu skipped over a release and it upgraded from
Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 23.04.

Most likely you'll have to backup your data using an Ubuntu live USB to access your stored files, and fresh install Ubuntu 22.04 again. A fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 should work OK.

Comment: The releases  like 22.04.1 and 22.04.2 are considered to be "point releases" and upgrading to the next point release via `sudo apt upgrade` is not the same thing as upgrading from one version of Ubuntu to another using `sudo do-release-upgrade`, for example from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to Ubuntu 22.10 or 24.04 LTS.